# Button not working

Tags: php, html

I want to create a button which will copy the directory address.
But by using the following code I am only getting the value of first item in `final_array`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Directory Listing</title>
    <script>
        function copyToClipboard(text) {
            window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $root = 'MyPictures/';

    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root,         RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
        );

    $paths = array($root);
    foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
        if ($dir->isDir()) {
            $paths[] = $path;
        }
    }
    $count = sizeof($paths);

    $new_arr;
    $final_arr;

    for($i=2;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $new_arr[$i] =  str_replace("MyPictures","", $paths[$i]);
        $final_arr[$i] = str_replace("\\","/", $new_arr[$i]);

        echo '<br>';
        echo '<button id="demo" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById(' . "'demo'" . ').innerHTML)">' . $final_arr[$i] . '</button>';    
        echo  '<br>';
    } 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Like by clicking any button I am getting first element in the copy dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you are using `ID` to specify your tag, `ID` must be unique within your document, it's a DOM fundamentals .

so , this line :

```
echo '<button id="demo" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById(' . "'demo'" . ').innerHTML)">' . $final_arr[$i] . '</button>';
```

should have a unique id instead of static `demo` id , **OR** simply use `class` as follows :

```
echo '<button class="demo" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById(' . "'demo'" . ').innerHTML)">' . $final_arr[$i] . '</button>';
```

the second part :

you may simply pass your HTML DOM element relatively using `this` object as follows:

```
echo '<button id="demo_'.$i.'" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML)">' . $final_arr[$i] . '</button>';
```